# How to solve the Problem in Eclipse IDE

Tags: android

I am adding some jar files into my application. At the time of adding jar's in Eclipse it gives the “Internal Error” alert.

The error message dialog says:

---

An out of memory error has occurred. Consult the "Running Eclipse" section of the read me file for information on preventing this kind of error in the future.
You are recommended to exit the workbench.
Subsequent errors may happen and may terminate the workbench without warning.
See the .log file for more details.

How to solve this.Can anyone help me??

Comment: Restart Eclipse. It solves every problem :P

Comment: After Restart it gives the error in problems 

"Conversion to Dalvik format failed: 
Unable to execute dex: null "

Answer (score 0):

Often times your Eclipse maximum heap has been overrun. Search for Eclipse documentation on how to increase Eclipse's memory allocation limit.